# Plotly: Error with pandas dataframe: module 'plotly.express.data' has no attribute

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, sunburst-diagram

Firstly, apologies if this is a silly question, this is my first time using plotly. I am trying to make a sunburst diagram using my 'actor' dataframe, but I get an attribute error when I attempt to do so:

**Error:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-2e5f13ef3c16> in <module>
----> 1 px.data.actor

AttributeError: module 'plotly.express.data' has no attribute 'actor'
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

I have the following packages imported at the top:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.io as pio
import plotly.express as px
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did the suggested solutions work out for you?

Comment: I didn’t realise plotly express had a load of pre-built data sets I could access through the .data attribute! When I ran the line without the call to plotly.data.actor (and adjusted my data frame based off further research), it produced a lovely sunburst diagram. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Happy to help! Plotly express is a real gem with lots of stuff to explore. I've only just begun myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you're assuming that `px.data.actor` somehow would make ***your*** dataframe `actor` available to plotly. And I can understand why since `px.data` will make ***some*** built-in datasets available to you, like `px.data.carshare()`:

```
    centroid_lat    centroid_lon    car_hours   peak_hour
0   45.471549       -73.588684      1772.750000 2
1   45.543865       -73.562456      986.333333  23
2   45.487640       -73.642767      354.750000  20
3   45.522870       -73.595677      560.166667  23
4   45.453971       -73.738946      2836.666667 19

[...]   

244 45.547171       -73.556258      951.416667  3
245 45.546482       -73.574939      795.416667  2
246 45.495523       -73.627725      425.750000  8
247 45.521199       -73.581789      1044.833333 17
248 45.532564       -73.567535      694.916667  5
```

To inspect all datatasets avaiable to you in the same manner, just run `dir(px.data)` to get:

```
['absolute_import',
 'carshare',
 'election',
 'election_geojson',
 'gapminder',
 'iris',
 'tips',
 'wind']
```

But since `actor` already is available to you (because you've presumably made it yourself), the line `px.data.actor()` is not necessary at all.

***P.S***

Running `px.express.carshare()` returns a pandas dataframe. To keep working with this dataframe it's best to assign it to a variable like this: `df_cs = px.data.carshare()`

Answer (score 1):

The error looks self-explanatory. I'm not really sure why calling the `.actor()` method is necessary in the code. `px.data` will load some datasets that are a part of the library. Some of these include `iris, tips, wind, ...` Since you already have the dataframe, this call is unnecessary.

[Here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/blob/master/packages/python/plotly/plotly/data/__init__.py) is an exhaustive list from the code.

Simply remove the line and it should work.